# passing object into function inside of a function - scope issue

Tags: javascript, angular

```
http:Http;

constructor(http:Http){
this.http = http;
}  

myFunction(){

//this.http works great here!

      this.providerobject.getSomething( function(err, result) {

      //this.http here is undefined! I need to use it here

.
.
.
```

With the code shown above I am trying to make an http request inside of the `provider.getSomething` function, but it seems the `this.http` object is undefined here! How can I make an http call inside of this function? I know it has somehting to do with scope as this object works outside of the `provider.getSomething` function. I do not know how to pass it in though. Say I do this:

```
 this.providerobject.getSomething(this.http, function(err, result) {
```

Well that would pass it into my provider function, but not this function. How can I use this object in that scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I don't work with Angular 2, but in most cases like these, the [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two approach,

you may store this into some variable say self and use it,

```
 let self = this;
```

or you may use fat arrow syntax, which takes care of `this`

```
let myFunction = ()=>{
   // this will be preserved here,
   this.providerobject.getSomething(this.http, function(err, result) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!